# Pouring stout without stout faucet

Tags: stout

My stout facuet has gotten lost in the post and I have a keg of Guinness, I have mixed gas (70/30)(N/Co2) and i was wondering what would happen if i didnt use the correct nozzel, using a beer tap?

I've tried to find answers online but can't seem to find out anything.

Answer (score 1):

If you push a regular tap back you can inject some nitrogen and it will even cascade but it isn't nearly as "creamy" as regular Guinness.

Answer (score 0):

With a standard faucet you can just gently crack it open to get some extra foam towards the end of the fill.  Maybe for the last third is what I have done.